# What's an idiomatic way of handling a lazy input channel in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state, monads, irc

I am implementing an IRC bot and since I am connecting over SSL by using OpenSSL.Session I use `lazyRead` function to read data from the socket. During the initial phase of the connection I need to perform several things in order: nick negotiation, nickserv identification, joining channels etc) so there is some state involved. Right now I came up with the following:

```
data ConnectionState = Initial | NickIdentification | Connected

listen :: SSL.SSL -> IO ()
listen ssl = do
  lines <- BL.lines `fmap` SSL.lazyRead ssl
  evalStateT (mapM_ (processLine ssl) lines) Initial

processLine :: SSL.SSL -> BL.ByteString -> StateT ConnectionState IO ()
processLine ssl line = do case message of
                            Just a -> processMessage ssl a
                            Nothing -> return ()
  where message = IRC.decode $ BL.toStrict line

processMessage :: SSL.SSL -> IRC.Message -> StateT ConnectionState IO ()
processMessage ssl m = do
    state <- S.get
    case state of
      Initial -> when (IRC.msg_command m == "376") $ do
        liftIO $ putStrLn "connected!"
        liftIO $ privmsg ssl "NickServ" ("identify " ++ nick_password)
        S.put NickIdentification
      NickIdentification -> do
        when (identified m) $ do
          liftIO $ putStrLn "identified!"
          liftIO $ joinChannel ssl chan
          S.put Connected
      Connected -> return ()
    liftIO $ print m
    when (IRC.msg_command m == "PING") $ (liftIO . pong . mconcat . map show) (IRC.msg_params m)
```

So when I get to the "Connected" state I still end up going through the case statement even though it's only really needed to initialize the connection. The other problem is that adding nested StateT's would be very painful.

Other way would be to replace `mapM` with something custom to only process lines until we are connected and then start another loop over the rest. This would require either keeping track of what's left in the list or invoking `SSL.lazyRead` once again (which is not too bad).

Another solution is to keep the remaining lines list in the state and draw lines when needed similar to `getLine`.

What's the better thing to do in this case? Would Haskell's laziness make it so that we go directly to `Connected` case after state stops updating or is `case` always strict?

Comment: Another alternative would be to use [conduit](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/conduit-overview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Pipe` type from `pipes`.  The trick is that instead of creating a state machine and a transition function you can encode the the state implicitly in the control flow of the `Pipe`.

Here is what the `Pipe` would look like:

```
stateful :: Pipe ByteString ByteString IO r
stateful = do
    msg <- await
    if (IRC.msg_command msg == "376")
        then do
            liftIO $ putStrLn "connected!"
            liftIO $ privmsg ssl "NickServ" ("identify " ++ nick_password)
            yield msg
            nick
        else stateful

nick :: Pipe ByteString ByteString IO r
nick = do
    msg <- await
    if identified msg
        then do
            liftIO $ putStrLn "identified!"
            liftIO $ joinChannel ssl chan
            yield msg
            cat  -- Forward the remaining input to output indefinitely 
        else nick
```

The `stateful` pipe corresponds to the stateful part of your `processMessage` function.  It handles initialization and authentication, but defers further message processing to downstream stages by re-`yield`ing the `msg`.

You can then loop over every message this `Pipe` `yield`s by using `for`:

```
processMessage :: Consumer ByteString IO r
processMessage = for stateful $ \msg -> do
    liftIO $ print m
    when (IRC.msg_command m == "PING") $ (liftIO . pong . mconcat . map show) (IRC.msg_params m)
```

Now all you need is a source of `ByteString` lines to feed to `processMessage`.  You can use the following `Producer`:

```
lines :: Producer ByteString IO ()
lines = do
    bs <- liftIO (ByteString.getLine)
    if ByteString.null bs
        then return ()
        else do
            yield bs
            lines
```

Then you can connect `lines` to `processMessage` and run them:

```
runEffect (lines >-> processMessage) :: IO ()
```

Note that the `lines` Producer does not use lazy `IO`.  It will work even if you use the strict `ByteString` module, but the behavior of the entire program will still be lazy.

If you want to learn more about how `pipes` works, you can read [the `pipes` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, trying Pipes now, they look awesome! Is it equivalent to using `await` in `processMessage` then doing `lines >-> stateful >-> processMessage`? Also, what's the best way to handle exceptions happened in the producer so that other pipes have a chance to gracefully clean up? For example I might want to spawn some threads in `stateful` but I would like to kill them whenever consumer hits EOF.

Comment: I guess I should look into Pipes.Safe.

Comment: Also, I'd like to handle ping messages first, so I switch stateful and processMessage places but then I have to do something like `forever await` in my stateful whenever it fully completes the registration. Is this bad in any sense?

Comment: I found out that using sequence makes this state machine even more visual:  `runEffect (messages con >-> handlePing con >-> sequence_ [nickNegotiation con, nickServId con, forever await])` and I can now change the order of things. (these consumers now return whenever they finish processing)

Comment: Yeah, `pipes-safe` handles anything related to resource clean-up.